# Selinux: changing root mapping

Tags: linux, kernel, selinux

I want to control some accesses of root in Linux- fedora, for example, I want to run a process and I want root not to be able to kill it.

I use SELinux and I changed root mapping from unconfined to guest_u:

```
Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

root                 guest_u              s0                   *
```

also, I changed my current account to root SELinux User mode. like this:

```
Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

my_user              root                 s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
root                 guest_u              s0                   *
```

theoretically, after registering changes by rebooting, my user must have grant root privileges and the root must be unable to do many actions and activities.
but this not happened. and my root still can do everything (enabled by sudo su - from current account) and my current account can't do what I want.

could someone explain to me what's happened there, after I registering changes? and why I cannot reach what I want here??

thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong direction. It helps to thoroughly understand the difference between DAC and MAC first. The gist is that MAC enhances DAC. Meaning that Linux identities are not the same as SELinux identities, and that if something is blocked by DAC then SELinux cannot override that, but if something is allowed by DAC then SELinux can still be used to block access.

In practical terms, just because you associated the my_user Linux identity with the root SELinux identity that does not make my_user root since from a DAC perspective my_user is still my_user.

However In reverse if you associate the root Linux identity with the guest_u SELinux identity then you're limiting the power of the root login user because even though from a DAC perspective root might be powerful SELinux still has the last say in the matter and the guest_u SELinux user was designed to be associated with guest login users (ie very little permissions from a MAC perspective)

So DAC is checked first and then after that MAC is checked. MAC cannot allow something that DAC blocks but MAC can block something that DAC allows.

As for prevention a root owned process access to signal other processes. It is not something I can run-down here in a few sentences but the gist is that security attributes are associated with processes, rules are associated with security attributes and all access is denied by default. So you have to associate a "label" with your processes and then use those labels and the available SELinux access vectors to govern how processes with given labels can interact or operate.

Comment: Great! I had some idea like you said about DAC and MAC, but I was not sure about this, and now I'm confident! thank you. but two question, is there any way to change DAC defaults? for example to give my_user root privileges? and the second one, I don't have any idea about your last part of answer. how should I do this? have you any link or etc for referencing?

Comment: The second question is very broad and there are a lot of variables. I think best I can do is point you to the SELinux Notebook: https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux-notebook/blob/main/src/toc.md. The answer to the first question is two-fold. You have to first understand what defines "root". Its generally two things: an identity with access to Linux capabilities. You cannot "copy" the former but you can associate ambient capabilities with user identities. So even though they will never a able to be "root", they can still have some of "root's" capabilties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance!